# Converting InputStream data to different datatypes

Tags: ios, xcode, inputstream

I have been working with InputStreams in Objective-C and seem to have taken the wrong step into the processing of the received data.

I am receiving chunks of bytes, which are read and converted to datatypes, as integers, floats, doubles etc.

So far my process is like this:

```
readBuffer = (uint8_t *) malloc(4);
memset(readBuffer, 0, 4);
while (length < byteLength) {
    length = [InputStream read:readBuffer 4];
}
[something fourByteUint8ToLong:readBuffer];
```

Now in order to do some converting from the 4-bytes to long

```
- (long) fourByteUint8ToLong:(uint8_t *) buffer
{
    long temp = 0;
    temp |= buffer[0] & 0xFF;
    temp <<= 8;
    temp |= buffer[1] & 0xFF;
    temp <<= 8;
    temp |= buffer[2] & 0xFF;
    temp <<= 8;
    temp |= buffer[3] & 0xFF;
    return temp;
}
```

Is there not an easier way to handle this by using the objective-C classes?

In that case how? 8-bytes -> double, 4-bytes -> float.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by using `CoreFoundation.h` class function:

```
uint8_t * buffer;
buffer = (uint8_t *) malloc(8);
double tempDouble = CFConvertFloat64SwappedToHost(*((CFSwappedFloat64*)buffer));
```